# No var assignment outside scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to understand how come the assignment of vm.Info var does not work properly. Sorry for the bad question.

```
 vm.getUser = function(email) {
             vm.Info = ''  

                authentication
                    .avvocatoByEmail(email)
                    .error(function(err){
                        return null;
                    }).success(function(data){
                        vm.data = { user : data };

                        vm.Info = $crypto.encrypt(vm.data.user[0].id + "." + vm.data.user[0].email, 'myKey');
                        console.log("Here ok: " + vm.Info);

                    });

                console.log("Here blank: " + vm.Info);
            }
```

Comment: It does work - it's just too late. Notice also the order of the logs in your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ajax call is asynchronous, and as a result, your second console.log (which isnt working) will get executed first; And once success event of ajax call is fired, the first console.log will work where you are assigning data to that variable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I figure it out. Thank you also to @Bergi